# Bash keybinding with "bind" - avoid recursion like noremap in Vim

Tags: bash, recursion, vim, keymapping

I've remapped the following keys in Bash:

```
bind '"a" "b"'
bind '"b" "c"'
```

If I press <kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>b</kbd> both times a `c` will be printed.

How can I map the keys so that by pressing <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>b</kbd> will be printed and only by pressing <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>c</kbd> will be printed (like with Vims `**nore**-map`)?

Comment: What is your use case? There might be a way to do this, but it sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: Hi, well my use case is to remap keys in bash without recursion ;) I already know how to remap keys in windows, mac and linux, but in this case I have to remap them without being able to modify the OS. Maybe there is a more global approach, like remapping keys in screen or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a char in the right part a literal with a preceeding "^V":

> bind '"x":"^Vx "'

The key sequence to enter the text after colon is:

> " Ctrl-v Ctrl-v x space "

In bash "Ctrl-v x" results in a literal x, without key-mapping interpretation .

Answer (score 0):

You may find it useful to build your own keymapping file which maps the numeric signal you get from the keyboard to a character. This is done with the `loadkeys` command i.e. if you're switching to the dvorak layout you can do (this is a verbose way to show you the location of the map files:

```
loadkeys /usr/share/keymaps/i386/dvorak/dvorak.map.gz
```

You could copy the map file for the layout you use and change the relavent chars, and load your modified mapping. I think loadkeys only affects the command line, though there are similar methods for changing the behaviour in X I believe.